# Copying or moving executable files via a vb6 program

Tags: vb6

I want to copy or move executable files from one location to another, say from a removable disc to a hard drive using a `vb6` program.
example - if I run my program, then a file from one location will be copied to another location. Please let me know how can this be done.

Comment: My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(from, to)

Comment: i said VB6, not VB.NET

Comment: Use FileSystemObject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `FileCopy` statement:

```vb
Dim sSource As String
Dim sDestination As String

sSource = "path\to\some\file.ext"
sDestination = "path\to\some\other\file.ext"
' Copies the source to the destination
Filecopy sSource, sDestination
```

You can also use the statement to change the copied file's name, just like a rename statement.

Answer (score 0):

As **Arvo** said in comments you can use FileSystemObject for more options. You can use it for writing, reading or deleting files.  To use it you must add a reference to  the project called "Microsoft Scripting Runtime".
Here's how you can define it:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
   Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject,Source as string,Destination as string
   Source="path\to\file.exe"
   Destination="path\to\folder"

   FSO.CopyFile(Source,Destination,false)
End Sub
```

As you can see you have an extra third option :"Overwrite" which can be optional (the default value is True).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change `path1` the file and `path2` the location for it

---

Copyfile path1 , path2